# Why is my Angular project on localhost:4200/#/ rather than just localhost:4200/?

Tags: angular

I am using an Angular premade dashboard for my project, however for all the pages, it has a /#/ in the URL.

Does anyone know why this is?

[Image of URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQS6p.png)

Comment: Are you using the hash location strategy? https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

Comment: Yes, it appeared that I was. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because # is for a javascript navigation and don't reload the page with a new request

Answer (score 0):

When you use the hash location strategy, Angular includes a hash symbol (#) in the URL to indicate the beginning of the fragment identifier. For remove (#) follow this method.

```
import { PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
        @NgModule({
          // ...
          providers: [
            { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }
          ]
        })
    
    export class AppModule { }
```